# Extjs / Sencha: Locking columns in Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel - possible/how?

Tags: grid, extjs

I am trying to lock a couple of columns in Sencha's EditorGridPanel
It should look like this but in an editable grid:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/grid/locking-grid.html

According to examples I found on the web it should work with "locked: true".
Actually it does not.

Is my code broken or is the information just wrong? I am using ext.js 3.3.0

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
    title:'Editor',
    clicksToEdit: 1,
    enableColLock: true,
    store: store,
    columns: [
    {
        header: 'ID',
        width: 30,
        locked: true,
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: 'id',
        hidden: true
    },
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example in the sources
in examples/grid/locking-grid.html

You have to use a LockingColumnModel and the LockingGridView.

Answer (score 3):

If by "lock" you mean to make the column uneditable, you might be referring to the [Column.editable](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.grid.Column-cfg-editable) config option:

```
{
    header: 'ID',
    width: 30,
    editable: false,
    sortable: true,
    dataIndex: 'id',
    hidden: true
}
```

You can also update this value programmatically via [ColumnModel.setEditable( Number col, Boolean editable )](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.grid.ColumnModel-method-setEditable) like this:

```
grid.getColumnModel().setEditable(0, false);
```

Comment: No, my "locking" I mean "freezing", see http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/grid/locking-grid.html